# How to Set file variable name on execution

Tags: java, io, linked-list

How would I let the user decide the file name when running the program?? My file name is assigned to a variable called "f" and currently hardcoded, but how would i run the program and point to a certain file at the same time....for example

How do I assign this to "f"??

System.out.println("usage: java CheckBalanced ");

```
   ListReferenceBased stack = new ListReferenceBased();
    int exception=0;
     File f=new File("ef.txt");


     FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: pass file name as command line arg http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your usage message like

```
System.out.println("usage: java CheckBalanced <FILE>");
```

Then,

```
File f=new File((args.length < 1) ? "ef.txt" : args[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I suggest you to use  Scanner class which is present in java.util package so you import this package in our program.

Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

Here Scanner is the class name, a is the name of object, new keyword is used to allocate the memory and System.in is the input stream. Following methods of Scanner class are used in the program below :-
1) nextInt to input an integer
2) nextFloat to input a float
3) nextLine to input a string

in your case you can use string (nextLine)
```

your code should look something like this

```
ListReferenceBased stack = new ListReferenceBased();
int exception=0;
 // add the following code
  String fileName;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the file name in .txt");
  fileName = in.nextLine();


 File f=new File(fileName);     

 FileReader fr = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(f);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this has a main method, than do the following:

You can invoke the program through `java CheckBalanced PathToFileName` where PathToFileName is the location of the file on the file system.

An example would be `java CheckBalanced "C:/ef.txt"`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pathToFile = args[0];

    ListReferenceBased stack = new ListReferenceBased();
    int exception = 0;
    File f = new File(pathToFile);

    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```